# Can every possible curve be expressed mathematically

Tags: plane-curves

Can every possible curve/parabola shown on a graph (for example $x^2$ or somthing much more complicated) be expressed in an equation like $y=x^2$. Or are there some lines you can't express?

Comment: $\;y=x^2\;$ is not a line but a parabola. Perhaps the most general term is curve or function graph.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Comment: The number of mathematical expressions is countable, while the number of real-valued functions is not.

Comment: @Slade the number of mathematical expressions is not countable, think of infinite series. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: What restrictions are you placing on the curve? Presumably you want it to be continuous. But that is a weak restriction. You might want it to be smooth?

Comment: @Henrique I do not see the problem.

Comment: The answer is yes; trivially let $C$ be a curve. The question should rather be, can every curve be described as $F(x)=0$ where $F$ is a composition of a finite number of elementary functions (or, if you wish, plus a few more, like the Gamma function, etc). Then, the answer is no.

Comment: @Slade "The number of mathematical expressions is countable" That's an interesting statement. It directly leads to the question: "What is a mathematical expression?"

Comment: Not only can most curves not be written down. Most real numbers (or constant functions) cannot be written down. The numbers that can be written down fall under the heading of Computable Numbers, of which there are only countably many. It should be easy to convince yourself that if a number can be specified by a finite sentence of words and symbols then we can get a computer to spit out the decimal expansion for that number (however spitting out the entire expansion will take forever.)

Comment: @Slade: Of course if you can specify the elements of a sequence, for example $a_n = (-1)^k/(2k-1)$, you can specify the infinite sum (if it converges), for example $-\pi$. But they we have to ask how many sequences can we actually "write down". This has the same problem as for real numbers -- only countably many sequences are computable. Indeed looking back to real numbers shows there are only countably many computable sequences with entries in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$